# What anime has a character becoming aware of cows suffering when eating a burger?

Tags: story-identification, anime

So I can't remember very much about this anime, but as far as I remember it was set in a real world, present-day setting and the main character somehow got some kind of powers.

But there is a scene that I remember: after she became aware of her powers, she went to eat with her friends at some kind of restaurant, where they ordered burgers and then the main character heard a voice, which told her something like "How can you still eat that, now that you can see?" and after that the girl saw the cows, from which the burgers were made of, screaming in pain in some sort of flashback.

I know that's not very much and I can't remember names, just the feeling that the film told us how bad most humans are and I think the main character was chosen to rescue mankind or something like that.

It must be 5–10 years ago that I watched that movie, but for some reason I get flashbacks and deja vus from it in the last 3-4 days.

I really appreciate your help and I'm sorry for my bad English, I tried my best x:

Comment: Can you be more specific than "years ago"? 2? 5? 10? 20? Even just a rough timeframe would help. Was it in English? Was it a dub (as far as you can tell)? Did it seem to be an episode of a series, or a movie?

Comment: I think it was in english, I watched it in TV and it must be about 5-10 years I think

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like it could be [Earth Girl Arjuna](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=602).

Per Orbit's own comment; "*Earth Girl Arjuna is about a girl named Juna who died of a motorcycle accident, but during an out-of-body experience she meets a spirit who offers her to help her save the world and restore her life, so she agrees and starts to live again, but from now on she's gifted with the ability to see the misdoings of mankind, like when she tries to eat a burger she sees images of the suffering cows or rotten meat and pesticides the burger is made of. Also she can transform into something called the Avatar of time, to save the world*"

Comment: that's it (: thank you very much.

Comment: In the interest of this answer being useful to others in the future, and in case the link goes stale, could you elaborate in a short paragraph why Earth Girl Arjuna is the right show?

Comment: Earth Girl Arjuna is about a girl named Juna who died of a motorcycle accident, but during an out-of-body experience she meets a spirit who offers her to help her save the world and restore her life, so she agrees and starts to live again, but from now on she's gifted with the ability to see the misdoings of mankind, like when she tries to eat a burger she sees images of the suffering cows or rotten meat and pesticides the burger is made of. Also she can transform into something called the Avatar of time, to save the world. And that's what I was looking for.

Comment: And I think I had these deja vus, because I've recently started to play Pokemon Emerald again ^^ And the "Avatar of Time" looks a bit like the legendary Pokemon "Deoxys" :D

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - Sorted